# migrations aborted foreign key constrainst

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm trying to create a database in MySql with some data that already exist. Its based on erghast db. I want to reference another table but I get an error message even though I referenced that same table the same way just before

```
class CreateRaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :races do |t|
      t.integer           :year,        null: false
      t.integer           :round,       null: false
      t.references        :circuit,   foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.string            :name,        null: false
      t.date              :date,        null: false
      t.time              :time,        null: true
      t.string            :url,         null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My races table is created.
Then I do this, and about 3 or 4 other ones that works.....

```
class CreatePitStops < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table  :pit_stops do |t|
      t.references :race,       foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.references :driver,     foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.references :stop
      t.integer     :lap
      t.time        :time,         null: true
      t.string      :duration,     null: true
      t.integer     :milliseconds, null: true
    end
  end
end
```

BUT, when I tried this one

```rb
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.references :race, foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.references :driver, foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.references :constructor, foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
      t.integer     :number,          null: true
      t.integer     :grid,            null: false
      t.integer     :position,        null: true
      t.string      :positionText,    null: false
      t.integer     :positionOrder,   null: false
      t.integer     :points,          null: false
      t.integer     :laps,            null: false
      t.string      :time,            null: true
      t.integer     :milliseconds,    null: true
      t.integer     :fastestLap,      null: true
      t.integer     :rank,            null: true
      t.string      :fastestLapTime,  null: true
      t.string      :fastestLapSpeed, null: true
      t.references :status,        foreign_key: {on_update: :cascade}
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error in console saying

```
Column `race_id` on table `results` does not match column `id` on `races`, which has type `bigint(20)`. To resolve this issue, change the type of the `race_id` column on `results` to be :bigint. (For example `t.bigint :race_id`).
Original message: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint
/home/me/Documents/source/repos/Projects/F1_API/db/migrate/20190802234105_create_results.rb:3:in `change'
```

Edit; I already tried to add type: :bigint in there.

I Just realised, can it be because of the name of the table "results"?
Because the other table that gives the the same problem is named "constructor_results"

Ruby 2.6.3p62
Rails 6 rc2
MySQL 14.14 distrib 5.7.26

Comment: @muistooshort same...

Comment: What version or Rails and MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Schwern Ruby 2.6.3p62
Rails 6 rc2
MySQL 14.14 distrib 5.7.26

Comment: @petebdeblois Rails 6 is still in development, could be a bug. I'd suggest trying it with the latest master, and also the latest stable.